# Using Bootsfaces Datatable- Not able to use dataTableColumn

Tags: jsf, datatable, bootsfaces

I m using Bootsfaces0.9.1. When i try to use the bootsfaces datatable as suggested in showcase, i am not able to use b:dataTableColumn tag. It says that the "value" attribute is not defined in  b:dataTableColumn tag.

```
<b:dataTable value="#{bookingAdminController.itemsBookDet}" var="items">
    <b:dataTableColumn value="#{items.}"
</b:dataTable>
```

I am not able to access "items" in value attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, that's a bug (or feature) of Netbeans. The application works, but your IDE shows an error (or a warning). Either use BootsFaces-0.9.2-SNAPSHOT (see [issue #369 on the BootsFaces GitHub repository](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=369) to see how to get it), ignore the squiggly lines or use another IDE. You can also use the standard `h:column` tag, but in this case, the other attributes aren't supported by your IDE.

There's also a (solved) [bug report on the BootsFaces bug tracker](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/510) which addresses the problem.

Please note that the snapshot version is a developer preview. Don't use it in production.

Comment: Great! Always glad to help! Just for the record: which of the options I offered works for you?